# How to include boolean options in a python function

Tags: python

How do I include a boolean option in my python functions?  For instance in panda's library there is a method .sort_values()
has a parameter called ascending which is by default True but if set to False the function will sort differently.  The details of the method are unimportant to my question, if you are curious you can read about the details of .sort_values(): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

The point is that dataframes has a parameter acsending which is by default true
Pandas.DataFrame.sort_values(self, by, axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last)

How do I write a function with a parameter like ascending.  Suppose I write a function called make_it_more that takes an integer or float x and adds one to it.  With an option which if set to true will return x+2.  How would I write that function?

```
def make_it_more(x, one_more=False):
    y=x+1
    if one_more==True:
        y=y+1
    return y
```

How could I write make_it_more so that it knows to only respond to one_more=True, do functions like .sort_values() check for specific strings and return errors if non-matching strings are given?

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? Any errors? One: `if one_more=True:` should be `if one_more:`.

Comment: your current code works correctly. I don't see where is the problem. I would only write `if one_more:`, eventually `if one_more is True:`

Comment: I'm just confused about functions like .sort_values() where there are multiple of these "options" as parameters you can turn on or off.  for instance .sort_values() and I'm curious how python knows whether your turning the option on or off.  Is it entirely based on the position of the input argument in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is`, like this:

```
def make_it_more(x, one_more=False):
    amount_to_make_it_more_by = 2 if one_more is True else 1
    return x + amount_to_make_it_more_by
```

Otherwise you run into problems like this:

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 1 is True
False
```

Comment: even shorter `return x + (2 if one_more is True else 1)` but maybe less useful as answer for beginner :)